# how long would a insert query averagely take if the tables involved go over 20million rows in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, insert

i got this little school project which involves postgresql but its been 1 hour after running the following command and its still not done:

```sql
INSERT INTO series_has_performer(serie_id, performer_id) 
  (SELECT series.serie_id, performers.performer_id
    FROM series, performers WHERE series.title = performers.title and 
      series.title like '%''%' and series.ep_name = performers.ep_name);
```

where as the list series is about 3.3million rows long and the list performers 36million rows long.
i have also already disabled autocommit and add the foreign key after the insert is done.
is there something im doing wrong been googling all day and some forums said i should just copy the files into a csv file and then use those to copy into the wanted table but that seems like quite an inefficient way to do it to me. any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the insert is blocked by another session? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: Are you sure it's the `INSERT` that's slow, and not the `SELECT`? How long does the query take on its own?

Comment: please post at least expected plan for SELECT, also select into (insert into select) construct won't perform that much worse then copy I believe, but you can always try with limited set of data instead of googling ang asking - btw - try and tell is it that much faster?..

Comment: okay so i did only the SELECT part with a LIMIT of 100 and even that takes ages even though filling a diffrent table of say 4million took like 2min so did i do something wrong in the SELECT part?